# How should contrition (repentance for sins) be performed?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, worship, shiva-purana, sin

If I worship or chant a mantra, is it considered contrition i.e., repentance for my sins or is contrition done differently?

What do scriptures say about contrition? The right way to do it?

I heard that in Shiva Purana, Narada abuses Lord Vishnu, so Vishnu tells him that incantation of Shiva's mantra can give him contrition (i.e., Shiva can pardon him for his sins).

So if we perform incantation in mind or chant a mantra out loud, is it considered contrition the right way? If not, as per Hinduism, how should contrition be performed?

Fasting on an ekādaśī is different, here, I am only talking about incantation (chanting a mantra).

Comment: Do u mean atonement for sins by chanting mantras?because contrition means repentance,remorsefulness..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Yudhisthira says,’…a perpetrated sin is expiated by auspicious acts,
>   by publishing it wildly, by repentance, by alms-giving, by penances,
>   by trips to tirthas after renunciation of everything, **by constant
>   meditation** on the scriptures. Of all these, he that has practiced
>   renunciation is believed to be incapable of committing sins anew. ‘

Mahabharata Santi Parva Section VII

Worship, mantra japa and meditation done sincerely will be considered as contrition.